# Почему не равны одинаковые строки?

Tags: python

Здравствуйте.
Очень странная проблема. 
открываю файл, с двумя строками:

```
привет
пока
```

Вот код:

```
with open('fin', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    for line in file:         
        if message.text.find(line) != -1:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "OK")
```

и здесь `message.text` равен `привет`, но это не работает и что ещё интереснее, если `message.text` равен `пока`, то есть последней строки в файле, то это работает. Почему так?

Comment: Выводите в консоль значения line и message.text, а не пытайтесь угадать :)

Comment: Выводил, они одинаковы!

Comment: Перевод строки видите? Нет! А он есть :Р

Comment: Возможно, у вас в сообщении в конце строки нету символа перевода строки. Однако в циле в переменной line этот символ будет для каждой строки кроме последней. Выводить переменные стоит так: `print(repr(line), repr(message.text))`

Comment: Добавьте перед проверкой: `line = line.strip()`, это обрежет невидимые символы, типа пробелов и перехода на следующую строку

Comment: Или поменяйте порядок проверки. Сейчас проверяете из текста в строку, т.е. message.text ('привет') и line ('привет\n'), и из 'привет' не получится найти 'привет\n', а вот наоборот -- получится

Comment: Да, у строки line был знак \n. `line.strip()` помогло. Спасибо!

Comment: @M.Sheremain: добавьте это в виде [своего ответа](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) или gil9red попросите.